# Unable to install MariaDB on CentOS 6

Tags: centos6, mariadb

I am trying to install MariaDB on CentOS6. I have added repo file as per the instruction from Mariadb official webstite.

```
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/5.5/centos6-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
```

But yum unable to find the packages.

No package MariaDB-devel available.
No package MariaDB-client available.
No package MariaDB-server available.

I would like to get solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: What's the output of `yum repolist all`

Comment: Solved it I got repo from another website.

Comment: Here is the repo  wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo http://mariadb.if-not-true-then-false.com/centos/$(rpm -E %centos)/$(uname -i)/10                               Run this command.